# Rebasing against master vs against current branch?

Tags: git, rebase

If I have a feature branch I've been working on and want to clean it up, like squashing all the commits into 1 commit, would I:

1. rebase against the first commit of that feature branch `git rebase <COMMIT>`; or
2. against master? `git rebase -i master`

I am not sure the use case and differences of both.

Comment: Take a look at `git rebase --onto` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942588/difference-between-rebase-master-and-rebase-onto-master-from-a-branch-deri Other method would be to checkout master, merge in your branch, and then squash commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could use any of the following:

```
git rebase -i the-other-branch
# pick the first revision, squash the others. That will work
```

You could also do what I do:

```
git merge -m "Getting updates from main branch" master # do not worry, we will get rid of this revision next
git reset --soft master # now all differences between your branch and master (in other words, all changes related to your feature branch) will be in index
git commit -m "My feature"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks.  `the-other-branch` being master or the feature branch im on??

Comment: That would be master