# Is there a less cumbersome way to do this rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I sometimes find myself in the situation below and want to rebase C onto B:

```
       B
     /
   A
     \
       C <-- HEAD
```

I find that if I simply do `git rebase B`, I often get lots of warnings about "falling back to merge strategy" and "automatically resolving" conflicts.  Sometimes I straight up get a conflict.

So what I've taken to doing instead is `git rebase A --onto B`.  This almost always succeeds with no warnings or conflicts.

I don't really understand the difference between these 2 commands and why the first one is more problematic. Is there a less cumbersome way to do what I want without having to specify 2 different commits?

(for example: `git rebase --some-magic-switch B`)?

**EDIT:**
Just for added clarity, the desired result is:

```
A -- B -- C' <-- HEAD
```

Both `git rebase B` and `git rebase A --onto B` get me to the desired result.  The only difference is that the first one produces warnings and sometimes conflicts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'rebase master' and 'rebase --onto master' from a branch derived from a branch of master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942588/difference-between-rebase-master-and-rebase-onto-master-from-a-branch-deri)

Comment: Is that really `A --onto B`? Not `C --onto B`?

Comment: Does this answer you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942588/difference-between-rebase-master-and-rebase-onto-master-from-a-branch-deri

Comment: `git rebase B` is exactly the right command to go from the pictured initial state to the desired final state.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Both of the commands go the same desired state... but the simpler one often produces warnings

Comment: @rolf82 yes it's correct

Comment: If your history graph looks like shown, both commands should be absolutely identical. Not sure why there would be more conflicts. Can you provide a [mre] with the required steps?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any warnings or conflicts, but if you want to be really explicit:

```
git rebase --onto B A C
```

This will take all commits in the range `A..C` and copies them on top of B.

Of course, conflicts can still occur if there are actual conflicts, e.g. C changes the same lines that B changed.